# I want to redirect original Error Page. (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

My professora :D

I don't want to create an error process for errors that would only appear when unlucky, e.g. "ORA-00055: maximum number of DML locks exceeded".

But if I don't do anything about it, APEX show the error log screen. I don't like that thing.
Is it possible to change the error screen in the settings within the Application?

For example, displays a message "Please wait some time and then execute again" with an image of a cute cat.

Thank you for your kindness that tried to answer my question.
And imagining a picture of a cute cat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done this myself since I'm not that fan of cute cats when I get errors in my application but this is how I would go about doing it.

In apex the look and feel of pages, regions, buttons, lists, etc is configured in *templates*. So if you want to change how something looks, templates is the place to look.

1. Look up what template is used for the error page. Navigate to "Shared Components > Themes > #your theme# > Component Defaults" and look for "Error Page".
2. In my case the value is "Standard" so that needs to be changed. Navigate to "Shared Components > Templates" and look for the *Page template* "Standard". Take a copy and name it "My template with Cat".
3. Modify the template to your needs. Add the cat picture here.
4. Modify the Component Default in step (1) from "Standard" to "My template with Cat"

Note that this will work for apex error only. If you are encountering ORDS errors, it will go to the default ORDS error page (no idea how to change that).

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion fit me very well :D